# non-linear mixed integer programming question

Tags: integer-programming

I tried this question over in the algorithms section of stackoverflow and never really got a handle on the problem. I know it concerns non-linear mixed integer programming.

[In the following, 1...n and k are subscripts.  n will be relatively small - like say 5-20, or something like that. No more than a second or two to solve computationally, but I can cut it off after some time limit.]

Say you have C1...Cn, and some some positive integer M.  (C1...Cn are positive constants and need not be integers.  M will incidentally always be 127.)   Can you find a postive scaling factor s and a group of integers t1...tn each less than or equal to M (and greater than 0) such that the following objective function is minimized:

summation[for k=1 to n] of (abs(tk*s - Ck)).

Sort of akin to some variant of the knapsack problem or something else maybe?  I don't know.  Haven't really done non-linear programming before.

Comment: Is your $s$ an integer?

Comment: No s does not have to be an integer.  Also, contrary to what I wrote previously, C1...Cn do not all have to be greater than M. t1...tn do all have to be less than or equal to M.

Comment: This may not be what you think. Experiment with $n=2$ and the continued fraction approximation
$$ \frac{p}{q} \sim \frac{C_2}{C_1} $$
then take $t_1 = q$ and $t_2 = p .$ Then pick your best $s.$ The result will be good because 
$$ \frac{C_2}{p} \sim \frac{C_1}{q} .$$ Requires further thought for $n \geq 3.$ I was looking for the PSLQ method but I think your problem goes in another direction. Anyway, read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_relation_algorithm   
for now. Also, what is this for?

Comment: I have a page with various graphical elements on it. THese graphical elements have varying nonintenger "sizes". This is the (C1...Cn).  The entire page needs to be converted to another format in which the size of graphical elements can only be expressed as integers less than or equal to 127, but all the elements on the new page can be scaled up by a single scaling factor s.  So I want the graphical elements in the new format to be as close in size as possible to their size on the old page.  I know I 'm being vague about the specific platform, but the above accurately characterizes the problem.

Comment: Just a quick persual of that integer algorithm leads me to the following observation.  Their scenario has multiple specific real numbers as given, that you then determine an integer relation for.  In my case there is only one real number, s, but it is one of the unknowns, (along with the integers t1...tn) and not a given. So it seems like a significant difference to me, but I'll keep reading.

Comment: But wait -  I guess the C1...Cn are real.

Comment: I guess my point was in the integer relation algorithm you're multiplying mutiple given reals by integers which are initially unknown.  In my case the multiplication is between one real s and multiple integers and s is also one the unknowns.  

Comment: But then again: "The second application [of integer relation algorithms] is to search for an integer relation between a real number x and a set of mathematical constants..."

Comment: For a given s the problem is easy. We want to minimize $|t_i*s - C_i|$, so suppose we could solve it exactly: $t_i = C_i/s$. Now we have to try only 2 candidates per $t_i$: $min(M,floor(C_i/s))$ and $min(M,ceil(C_i/s))$. So for a given s we can solve the problem quickly. I did this for a sample input and plotted s versus the resulting error $\sum |t_i*s-C_i|$. The result http://i.imgur.com/zcKOW.png The error is very high if you choose s much to small or much too large. Choosing s around $max {t_i}/M$ seems to get good results, perhaps good enough for your purposes.

Comment: Correction: choose s round $max C_i/M$.

Comment: Actually maxCi/M is what I was already using - though it still seemed to  result in noticeable discrepancies for other C's.  

Comment: Perhaps you can search for s around maxCi/M, it seems that the total error can be reduced by roughly a factor of 3 versus just picking s=maxCi/M.

Comment: Appears you have part of it. Anyway, this task is the other extreme from PSLQ. Given your vector $ C_1, C_2, \ldots, C_n$ you want integer points $t_1, t_2, \ldots, t_n$ that are very close to the the line given by scalar multiples 
$S C_1, SC_2, \ldots, SC_n$ as that way, taking $s = 1/S,$ you get
 $ s t_1, s t_2, \ldots, s t_n$ fairly close to  $ C_1, C_2, \ldots, C_n.$ Having bounds on the $t_j$ complicates things, of course. But at heart, you want integer (lattice) points near a parametrized line.

Comment: If you don't have a bound on t_i then the problem is trivial. You can get arbitrarily close by just making t_i huge and s small.

Comment: Interesting. I'm not sure how to do that for $n=3,$ and the method for unbounded $t_j$ with $n=3$ might hint at methods for bounded $t_j .$  As noted the cases $n \leq 2$ give the wrong impression of this problem, while $n > 3$ can wait for a while.

Comment: Unless you meant, take any huge $S$ as in my comment an hour ago, just round all to a nearby lattice point $ t_1, t_2, \ldots, t_n,$ then when you take $s = 1/S$ you get $ s t_1, s t_2, \ldots, s t_n$ and
$ C_1, C_2, \ldots, C_n$ arbitrarily close.

Comment: definitely appreciate the feedback fromm you guys.  I'm not a mathemtician, but it looks like you've given me enough here to develop something, e.g. searching around maxCi/M,  the PSLQ algorithm , etc. 

Comment: To Jules  of course there is a bound on Ti - it has to be smaller than M (127).

Comment: Actually, after processing the thread more fully it appears we have not fully converged on a solution - which is intriguing in and of itself -  but it looks like you've given me enough to focus further research

Comment: Jules your original comment I guess constitutes a solution, if the search is around maxCi/M - I'll look into it.  OK that's all for me.

Comment: Here is the method I conceived just now for deriving and upper and lower bound for s when conducting the search for optimal s:  After deriving s = max(Ci)/M, it results in all elements of size max(Ci) to be sized exactly correct on the page.  I can then adjust this s upwards or downwards to become sk, which is a scaling factor that results in accurate sizes for all elements of size Ck. (I won't translate my C++ code for this into a compact math expression at this point.) But the bounds for searching for optimal s will be min(si), max(si).

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, I ended up just brute-forcing it, but using the solution provided in the first comment by Jules in the OP for finding optimal t1...tn when s is given.  I just iterate through s .0001 at at a time from 0 to 20 (s will never be higher than that) and it takes about a second and well worth it.  Its far preferable to the results obtained by just using s = max(C)/M.

Answer (score 1):

To support Mark's and Jules' observation that max(Ci)/M is a good starting point, I mention the following.  Suppose an initial value r was chosen in an attempt to
find s.  If the Ci were all less than (M+1)r, the total error would be at most n*r, since
one could find positive integers ui with (ui-1)r <= Ci <= ui*r, and one of ui, ui-1 would
be in the range 1 to M.   So smaller r means smaller worst case error.

Also, if one has a trial r and computes ui based on r, then
looking at sum ui*ei, where ei is the sign of the error ui*r - Ci, one has an indication of which direction to tweak r to reduce the amount of sum abs(ui*r - Ci), while keeping the
same values ui.

Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2010.06.11

Answer (score 1):

(This is in response to Gerhard Paseman's answer.)

```
                 .0001            .001 
maxC/M           2.528183          2.528183 
calculated s     4.459300          8.917000 
total error      2.703720          2.718460
```

The above represents two runs - one incrementing by .0001 and the other .001 (from 0 to 20 in both cases).  One trend is that  the difference in total error between .001 and .0001 is absolutely consistent with the above, regardless of the data.  The total error is in this case divided between 6 elements, each element averaging about 200 in size. If maxC/M were used as s, the total error would have been something like 7 or higher.)

But as to your observation regarding maxC/M being a good starting point for finding s, you can see above what s turned out to be.   When using .001 as the increment, s was often much higher than with .0001,  (with a consistent reduction in the size of the values for t).  So maybe with increasing precision in the search, s  converges towards the vicinity of maxC/m, but the example above has thus far seemed to be fairly typical. Haven't completely digested your remarks above yet. Thanks for letting a non-mathematician like me crash the party here.

Comment: I predict, with a precision run of .00005, you will get an s with
a value at or near 2.97255 with an error value less than 2.69 on the same input.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2010.06.11